# CORS headers missing from response when POST with invalid JSON in AWS Api Gateway API

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, post, cors, aws-api-gateway

We have an AWS API Gateway API that works for CORS most of the time. The only exception is when POSTing with invalid JSON, when CORS headers are missing from the response. If it is a valid JSON but it fails data validation, then the CORS headers are correctly set. I tried to reset the root resource by 'enable CORS' for root resource and redeploy, the same situation.

Just wondering if anyone has seen this before and how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

found the answer myself. If APIG has not reached integration in this case, need to customize the gateway response
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html